# Pandas pivot_table calculate running index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PART_UNIT': ['A','A','A','A','A'],
    'FiscalYear': ['2015/2016','2016/2017','2017/2018','2018/2019','2019/2020'],
    'BUY_UNIT_PRICE': [30,32,33,31,35]
})
```

That I have converted into a pivot_table

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index='PART_UNIT', columns='FiscalYear', values='BUY_UNIT_PRICE', aggfunc='mean')
print(pivot)

FiscalYear  2015/2016  2016/2017  2017/2018  2018/2019  2019/2020
PART_UNIT
A                  30         32         33         31         35
```

I am looking for help in determining the development from year to year

- 2015/2016 = index 100
- 2016/2017 = (2016/2017 value) / (2015/2016 value) * 100
- 2017/2018 = (2017/2018 value) / (2016/2017 value) * 100
- ...

My desired output for this example data would be

```
FiscalYear  2015/2016  2016/2017  2017/2018  2018/2019  2019/2020
PART_UNIT
A                 100     106.67     103,13      93,94      112,9
```

How would I go about doing this in Pandas?

The function I am after is identical to the one in excel pivot table where you can choose "show values as % of previous year"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [`pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) over `axis=1` and then [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by 100 and finally [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) 100 to match the expected output:

```
m=(df.pivot_table(index='PART_UNIT', columns='FiscalYear', 
                       values='BUY_UNIT_PRICE', aggfunc='mean'))
```

---

```
m.pct_change(axis=1).mul(100).add(100,fill_value=0)
```

---

```
FiscalYear  2015/2016   2016/2017  2017/2018  2018/2019   2019/2020
PART_UNIT                                                          
A               100.0  106.666667    103.125  93.939394  112.903226
```

Comment: Works like a charm
How about the case where I only have a price in 2016/2017 and in 2017/2018, here i would like 2016/2017 to be index 100 and 2017/2018 to be 103.125 the rest of the fields should be NULL

Comment: @HenrikPoulsen how about `m.where(m.isna(),m.pct_change(axis=1).mul(100).add(100,fill_value=0))`